# How to calculate the time complexity of this code

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, analysis

I have to calculate the time complexity of the code below using the Big-O notation. I got `O(nlogn)` as an answer.

- Input/output statements O(1)
- Inner loop O(n) because the it will output 1,2,4,8,..x (2^0 +2^1 + 2^2..2^x)
- Outer loop O(logn)
- The statements inside the outer loop logn (n)

- 

T(n) = O(1) + O(nlogn)
= O(nlogn)

But I am not sure. Can someone help me, please.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a number:");
int x = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
for(int i=1 ; i<x; i*=2) {
  System.out.print("*");
  for(int j=0; j<i;j++) {
    System.out.print(" ");
  System.out.println("*");
}
```

Comment: refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

As you found the time complexity is:

`T(x) = 1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^{log(x)}`

But you have a mistake in the result of the above summation. As `T(x)` is a geometric series with factor `2`:

`T(x) = 2^{log(x) + 1} - 1 = 2*x - 1`

So, it means `T(x)` is in `Theta(x)` and also `O(x)`.

Comment: for the whole code?
or only for the outer for loop?

Comment: @Jake Of course, It's the complexity of the whole code (outer and inner loop).